# How to automatically refresh when user logs out of the webapp?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, authentication, rbac

I have a web app and I can login as admin or customer in it. Admin has access to all pages, customer has access to certain pages only.

When customer logs in, the required pages, say 3 pages are shown, after he logs out and the admin loges in, still only those 3 pages are shown. Although, After manual refresh, I'm able to see all the required admin pages.

How do I refresh automatically when user logs out? I'm using Angular 10 framework.

Comment: What is your logic behind show/hide of restricted pages ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're question is pretty generic, it is hard to get into specifics.

You must have some login code, so presumably you are loading a users permissions from some system and storing those permissions as part of the app--presumably as a cookie?

You can protect routes using auth guards. We primarily use [canActivate guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

You can hide elements on a page--such as screen navigation links--with an [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf). We created our own [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) to accept in a list of allowed user permissions, and the current user's permissions and use that to determine if certain dom elements should be created or not.

I'm not sure about C#, but in Java we created a Spring Annotation to validate user permissions when a user tries to access a REST Endpoint. I suspect something similar must exist in the .NET world.

Conceptually it is not much different than our Angular custom structural directive; comparing allowed permissions to perform the action with user permissions, and then either allowing or denying the action.

It sounds like your users are getting elevated permissions by reloading the app; so I suspect there are some underlying security issues with your full implementation, but without a code review cannot begin to speculate what that is.